# B2: Attempt to redeclare already registered project id

Tags: comments, bjam, boost-build, b2

My jamfile was working fine and now I have the following error:

```
error: at jamfile:4
error: Attempt to redeclare already registered project id '/MyProject'.
error: Original project:
error: Name: Jamfile<C:\dev\MyProject>
error: Module: Jamfile<C:\dev\MyProject>
error: Main id: /MyProject
error: File: jamfile
error: Location: .
error: New project:
error: Module: Jamfile<>
error: File: jamfile
error: Location: .
```

This is quite surprising because there is a single jamfile, a single project, no other projects with the same name...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you used `//` to comment lines ? This was the reason why I had this error.

You must use `#` to comment lines in jamfiles.